# How do I concatenate different column value to single cell?

Tags: vba, excel

.
Hello guys,I need your inputs on the topic here.
I intend to combine or concatenate different value in different columns so its shown in a single cell.

Illustration is the following:
[image: Picture]

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZlIWv.jpg):

Is it possible to do this without macro?

Answer (score 3):

use

```
=CONCATENATE("The name of the painter: ",A3,CHAR(10), "The Hobby: ", B3, CHAR(10), "Tool used: ", C3,CHAR(10),"Remuneration: ", D3)
```

Comment: Hey thanks for answering! Do you by any chance know how to do this with macro?

Comment: Yes, I do. But you explicitly asked for a not-macro solution. So if this answer solved your _original_ question you may want to mark it as accepted. And if you need a macro solution you may post a new question specifying the minimum "environment". Thank you

Comment: @LukeHavelard, so did my answer solve your _original_ question?

Comment: Edit your post and remove the "Without macro" bit and replace it with "both with and without macros". You have already tagged VBA and the title doesn't specify so there will be no issue with misleading searches. I put the code below for you but user3598756 answered your first question correctly so mark their answer as the correct one.

Comment: @LukeHavelard, any chance to have you properly manage this post?

Answer (score 0):

To answer your second question on how to do it with code:

```
Sub PopulateResultsToCell()
    Dim X As Long, MyArr As Variant, PrefixArr As Variant
    PrefixArr = Array("The name of the painter: ", "The Hobby: ", "Tool used: ", "Remuneration: ")
    MyArr = Application.Transpose(Application.Transpose(Range("A3:D3"))) '<-- Change this for the range to read
    For X = LBound(MyArr) To UBound(MyArr)
        MyArr(X) = PrefixArr(X - 1) & Trim(MyArr(X)) 'Note: Option base is zero but transposing creates a base 1 array hence the X minus 1
    Next
    Range("F3").Formula = Join(MyArr, vbLf) '<-- Change this for where to populate the result to
End Sub
```